# Force.com Site - Direct User to Record Without Exposing Record Id in URL

Tags: force.com-sites, controller-extension

I have created a force.com site app for tracking reservations. I would like to be able to have my quests update/read their reservations after creation without using the Salesforce record Id in the url. Is there another way to accomplish this? Having the Ids exposed in the url feels loose.

Example of what I have been doing currently.

```
public PageReference updateReservation() {   

    PageReference page = new pageReference('https://sfse.force.com/site/myreservation?id='+ recordId);
    page.setRedirect(true);
    return page;
}


https://sfse.force.com/site/myreservation?id=a0923000000C6jnAAC
```

Comment: That does sound like an issue. If someone had their reservation id, they could just dial the number down by one and see the reservation of the person before them. The bigger problem might be that sensitive information is publicly visible.

Comment: @martin Exactly, from a security perspective it's way too loose for a public facing site. The reservations will store legal names, addresses, emails, phone numbers, etc.

Comment: There's not really going to be a good way of hiding the reservation id. Web browsers by design are going to know where they are navigating to. You will probably need to add extra security measures on the reservation page to make sure the person is able to view that information.

Comment: I solved this by using the name of the object in the url and running apex code to retrieve the name from the url and not the record id and query the data. This of course only works if you can guarantee that the name is unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're not using a Standard Controller, you could always encrypt the URL (Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV), then decrypt the parameter within your controller. Otherwise, if you are using a Standard Controller, you'd be stuck with what you're given. Note that Id values, while sequential, are so across the entire Salesforce platform; simply moving up and down by a single Id value at a time won't necessarily expose multiple records, especially if the records are created singly at sporadic intervals. Alternatively, you could also add a MAC (Message Authentication Code), and refuse to display any data without it. Your URL would then look like:

> https://mysite.force.com/site/reservation?id=...&mac=...

MACs are one-way hashes that can't be faked without the appropriate key. See the [Crypto](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm) class, especially generateMac, encryptWithManagedIV, and decryptWithManagedIV for more information.